# get M2M model from intermediate table name

Tags: django, django-models

I need to get access to m2m *model* from intermediate **table name**.
Example models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

so the table name is **group_person**, how can i access to it's *model* only from **name**?
Due to circumstances i can't use through/etc from parent/related model.
Im getting list of m2m tables names like this:

```
m2m_fields = model_class._meta.local_many_to_many
            if m2m_fields:
                for field in m2m_fields:
                    table = field.remote_field.through
                    intermediate_table_name = table.__name__
```

while iterating over some models
Thanks! Sorry for bad eng:)

Answer (score 1):

This can also be done like this

```
Group.members.through.__name__
```

OR db table name by

```
Group.members.through._meta.db_table
```

Comment: it still a reference from another model :(